# Error in background zoom?

Tags: css, wordpress, google-chrome, zooming

I have a WordPress website where I use Visual Composer with fullpage sections. I've added a zooming background using CSS. It's on the following URL: http://white-vision.nl/particulier/

```
.upb_row_bg {
animation: leaves 20s infinite;
}

@keyframes leaves {
0%, 100% {
    transform: scale(1.0);
}
50% {
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
}
```

It looks like it works great, but in Google Chrome when scrolling up (so from 3rd to 2nd section) it gets a white transparent overlay and the videobox is pushed down. When you scroll down (so from 1st section to 2nd section) everything works fine.

This is only a problem in Google Chrome (on Mac and Windows). It works fine in Firefox, Edge and Safari. Does anyone have an idea how to fix this? Thanks in advance!

PS: When deleting the zoom function, there is no problem.

Answer (score 0):

The parent element with classes `fp-tableCell vc_row-has-fill` is getting a change on its inline styles. One of the properties that are been changed is `opacity: 0.107967`. This is what makes your background look transparent.

You should try to access this element via javascript and force it to stay at `opacity: 1`. If you are not able to do that via script, you could force that elements' opacity by adding:

```
.vc_row-has-fill {
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

This will overwrite the changing opacity on the inline styles.